# How can I implement this UML Diagram using State Design Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C37H.png)
I have this UML Diagram and want to use State Design Pattern to implement InProgressState, HelpState and EscapeState.
Following is the details:

1. InProgressState: This is the initial state of the participant, and participants remain in this while they are solving the riddles.

- Within this state, solveRiddle checks whether the input solves the current riddle.

2. HelpState: This state is entered when the participant requests help by calling the askForHelp method.

- In this state, solveRiddle will solve the riddle regardless of the input provided.
  After that, the participant will be transitioned back to InProgressState if there are remaining riddles to solve, otherwise they will be transitioned to EscapedState.

3. EscapedState: If a participant successfully solves all riddles, they will be transitioned to the EscapedState.

- In this state, RiddleException should be thrown if solveRiddle is called.

Note:

1. If a riddle has been solved but passed as an argument to solveRiddle again, a RiddleException should be thrown.
2. A participant can choose any riddle to solve at a time. The argument whichRiddle of the solveRiddle method indicates to which riddle he/she submits an input in the riddleList.

I have a Class called ParticipantState:

```
public interface ParticipantState {
    ParticipantState solveRiddle(String input, Riddle[] riddleList, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException;
}
```

And I think InProgressState, HelpState and EscapedState should implements ParticipantState like:

```
public class InProgressState implements ParticipantState{

    @Override
    public ParticipantState solveRiddle(String input, Riddle[] riddleList, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the RiddleException is:
public class RiddleException extends Exception {
    public RiddleException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

code will be like

```
public class HelpState implements ParticipantState{


@Override
public ParticipantState solveRiddle(String input, Riddle[] riddleList, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException {
    Riddle riddle = riddleList[whichRiddle];
    if (riddle.isSolved())
        throw new RiddleException("Already Solved");

    riddle.setSolved();
    return new InProgressState();
}
}
```

and

```
public class InProgressState implements ParticipantState {
@Override
public ParticipantState solveRiddle(String input, Riddle[] riddleList, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException {
    Riddle riddle = riddleList[whichRiddle];
    if (riddle.isSolved())
        throw new RiddleException("Already Solved");
    return this;
}
}
```

and

```
public class EscapedState implements ParticipantState{


@Override
public ParticipantState solveRiddle(String input, Riddle[] riddleList, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException {
    throw new RiddleException("Alseady Escaped");
}
}
```

and

```
public void solveRiddle(String input, int whichRiddle) throws RiddleException {
    this.state = this.state.solveRiddle(input, riddleList, whichRiddle);

    // TODO  - Your Code Starts here

    boolean isEsacped = true;
    for (Riddle item :
            riddleList) {
        if (item.isSolved() != true) {
            isEsacped = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isEsacped){
        this.state = new EscapedState();
        for (Observer observer:
                observers) {
            observer.updateEscape(this);
        }
    }

    //TODO - Your Code Ends here
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try read a .csv file like this (in this case, we loaded the data to a list of Person class as the return value):

```
public List<Person> readCsv(String fileName) {

    List<Person> list = new LinkedList<>();

    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    File csv=new File(fileName);
    try{
        bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
        String buffer="";
        buffer=bufferedReader.readLine();//read the first line
        while (buffer!=null){
            String[] s=buffer.split(";");
            Person p =new Person(Integer.valueOf(s[0]),s[1],Integer.valueOf(s[2]),s[3]);
            list.add(p);
            buffer=bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("error in readcsv!");
    }

    return list;
}
```